# Redirect to homepage when trying access other URLs of my website

Tags: html, nginx, redirect

I have created a single page website with bootstrap. Some of the files which I don't want others to see, are accessible through the browser. 
[my .css file is directly accessible via https://www.matmerchants.com/css/bootstrap.css. my media files are directly accessible via https://www.matmerchants.com/media/file_name.ext ]

I want to redirect to the homepage, when someone try to access any URLs, other than the homepage.

**My default.conf**

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:8;
server_name matmerchants.com www.matmerchants.com;
return 301 https://www.matmerchants.com?$args;
}

server {
listen 443 ssl;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate     /usr/share/nginx/ssl/matmerchants.com.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /usr/share/nginx/ssl/matmerchants.com.key;  
ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers             HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

server_name     matmerchants.com www.matmerchants.com;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
error_log   /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;

location / {
root /usr/share/nginx/html/matm;
index index.html index.htm;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
}

}
```

Someone care to help me? :)

Comment: You can't do this. You must put the file there and the browser must be able to download it in order for the page to work at all. If you don't want people to learn the contents of your CSS or media files, you should not put them online.

Comment: In WordPress with All In One WP Security, I was able to restrict direct access to the media files. Is there anyway to do so?